# CakePHP 3: Creating Bootstrap radio buttons with Form Helper

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, cakephp-3.2

Whats the easiest way to get Bootstrap radio button structure using Form Helper. Desired structure is this:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

I tried changing form templates(values like 'radio' and 'radioWrapper'), but with no success.

Comment: Try this plugin, it will save you a lot of work https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to wrap this radio button div ? or you can create radio button like below code

```
   <div class="radio">
        <?php echo $this->Form->radio('optradio',['label'=>'options']); ?>
   </div>
```

For details [radio button](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons)